# Does the intrinsics functions from Intel Instrinsics Guide also works on AMD CPUs?

Tags: documentation, intel, amd

The link bellow is the Intel Instrinsics Guide for intrinsics functions. (SSE, AVX, etc.)

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#

Does this functions also works on a AMD CPU, with the exact same header files and function prototypes?
If not, where can I find the same guide for AMD CPUs?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to look at the specific CPU you want to run on. AMD supports many but not all instruction set extensions. Even within the Intel lineup there are large differences, with some extensions only being available in some generations (e.g. Icelake) or only in certain product lines (e.g. Atom and Core i7 but not Core i3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrinsics are function declarations that the compiler treats specially and maps directly to specific instructions for the processor.

Thus, it is the compiler vendor that determines what CPU instructions are available as intrinsics and their exact spelling in the source code. The CPU won't know if a particular instruction was given because the programmer called an intrinsic function or because the compiler decided that that instruction is the most appropriate for the non-intrinsic code that was written.

As intrinsics translate to processor instructions, AMD CPU's will support the same intrinsics as an Intel CPU if and when they support the same instructions.